# pulseIn only returning 0

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm new to arduino and I've searched through a lot of posts but can't find anything to fix the issue.

I'm trying to send a signal through some medium (water in this example) using a pizoelectric transducer and measure the time it takes for the signal to go from transducer to the other.

Attached is an image of the setup. Below is the code.

```
const int trigPin = 1;
const int echoPin = 0;
float duration;

void setup() {
  pinMode (trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (echoPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  // set transmitting pin to low
  digitalWrite (trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds (2);

  // send the signal
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (trigPin, LOW);

  // read in the signal on receiving pin, print duration to the Monitor
  duration = pulseIn (echoPin, HIGH);
  Serial.print("duration: ");
  Serial.print(duration);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

The issue is "duration" variable has been 0 in all of my tests. I've tried using various values for the timeout parameter in pulsIn to no avail. Any advice is appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

The most obvious is that you are using the wrong pins. On the Arduino
Uno, digital 0 is the serial RX pin, and digital 1 is TX. Thus, if you
use `Serial` in your sketch, you cannot use these pins for anything
else.

At a more fundamental level, it looks from your picture that you have
connected your Arduino to a couple of bare piezo transducers. Your code,
on the other hand, assumes the Arduino is connected to a digital sonar
module, like the very common [HC-SR04](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Isaac100/getting-started-with-the-hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-036380). You have to keep in mind that
a piezo transducer is an analog device. The sonar module, on the other
hand contains quite a few electronic parts that take care of
conditioning the analog signals and providing an easy to use digital
interface, where you just have to call `pulseIn()` to get the
measurement.

If you want to use the bare piezo transducers, the first thing you have
to do is *read their datasheet*. This is really essential. Once you have
read (and understood) that document, you can figure out whether or not
you need some interface electronics between the piezos and your Arduino.
Maybe you can get away with exciting the transmitter with PWM and
reading the receiver with the on-board ADC. Or maybe not. First read the
datasheet, then design your circuit, then test using a scope to look at
your signals.